# How to add colored triangles to the corner(s) of a cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I know by default triangles in red or green are indicators of warnings or comments. But what I need here is a solution to create a new format style to a cell, that can add, say four corners, or just one bottom-left corner, size-adjustable, position-selectable, triangle(s) to a cell.

Borders, shades, watermarks formats are great, but some do not look good during printing. That's the motivation I am seeking another format style solution. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do this. Excel reserves the red and green triangles as special indicators and I don't think you can override them.

Comment: Add a background image to the cell [Background image in single or multiple cells](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/707313-background-image-in-single-or-multiple-cells.html#post3077579)

Comment: @bdr9 No override, say, can I use brown color in the bottom right corner?

Comment: There s an article discussing this http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/80960-change-comment-indicator-color.html and a link which has code for this   https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!msg/microsoft.public.excel.programming/mSnOzRDy6Rk/C8T7fK7WlFEJ